# Prove that final position of vectors of length r rest on surface of sphere with radius r.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm trying to mathematically prove that two non-zero vectors in $R^3$ of length $r$ in standard position's tips rest on the surface of a sphere with radius $r$.

At first this seemed fairly straight-forward since the sphere represents every possible resting point of any vector in standard position of length $r$, but how do you **prove** that?

This is assuming $r > 0$ and $r$ is a valid real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S_r$ denotes the sphere with radius $r>0$ centered at $0$ what You actually want to prove is: $$S_r=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3:|x|=r\},$$
where $|.|$ denotes the euclidean norm.
If You define the sphere with radius $r$ by the above equation there is nothing to prove. If You define the sphere as the boundary of the ball with radius $r$ centered at $0$, i.e. $S_r=\partial B_r$, where
$$B_r=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3:|x|<r\}$$
then You argue like this: Every neighborhood of a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ with $|x|=r$
contains elements of $B_r$ and of $\mathbb{R}^3\backslash B_r$ (why?) and thus
$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3:|x|=r\}\subseteq S_r=\partial B_r$$ 
and every element that has only neighborhoods that contain elements of both $B_r$ and $\mathbb{R}^3\backslash B_r$ has to be of length $r$ and thus
$$S_r\subseteq\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3:|x|=r\}$$ Just fill in the details.
$\textbf{Hint:}$ for $r'\neq r$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ with $|x|=r'$ consider neighborhoods $U(x)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^3:|x-y|<\frac{|r-r'|}{2}\}$.